# How to train watson natural language classifier incrementaly?

Tags: ibm-watson, nl-classifier

I understand that you have to provide training data (in a csv file) when you create a natural language classifier.

If I want to add some more training data for the classifier when this data becomes available, how should I proceed ? Should I re create the classifier  with the original data + the new data ? Is there a way to send additional data to an existing classifier ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: I don't think this is possible right now. What you can do is to add the new samples to the training corpus and submit it to training again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Natural Language Classifier doesn't support retraining. Everytime the training data change you need to create a new classifier.